# Why are type variables for generics commonly declared as a single letter (e.g.: <T>)?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, static-typing, typescript-generics

For every example in the [TypeScript generics documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and in most type definition files I've came across, type variables are declared as a single letter, usually `<T>`.

Example:

```js
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

Questions:

- why are type variables for generics commonly declared as a single letter?

  - what are the reasons for doing this?
  - does it have a purpose other than convention and brevity?
- what are the pros and cons of using of more descriptive names?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Java docs for [Generics Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) has a really good paragraph about this - and it applies to all languages that supports type variables:

> #### Type Parameter Naming Conventions
>
> By convention, type parameter names are single, uppercase letters. This stands in sharp contrast to the variable naming conventions that you already know about, and with good reason: Without this convention, it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable and an ordinary class or interface name.
>
> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> ....
>
> T - Type

Basically you want to be able to quickly recognize that something is a type variable, and naming the type variable `T` just became a standard code convention at some point.

Microsoft's docs on [C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/generics-and-templates-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017) and [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) has this convention too.

Comment: The [C# guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters#type-parameter-naming-guidelines) actually recommend descriptive names prefixed with T, especially when there is more than one type parameter; thus `List<T>` but `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.